# Bluemix App Builder - Location is mandatory in a map screen

Tags: android, ios, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I'm trying to develop an app with the App Builder of Bluemix

I get the next error

> We have the following problems with the generation of application: Location is mandatory in a map screen 'Name of the screen'

How can I add the location?

Also I want to know if the app builder can help me to use geolocation

Answer (score 1):

The standalone mobile app builder service is deprecated and it’s features are now integrated into the Bluemix Mobile dashboard. You will be able to find the feature you're looking for in "Project Settings" after creating a new mobile project, where you'll need to add a Google api key.

Check out the blog post about the [New Mobile Dashboard](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2016/07/08/new-bluemix-mobile-dashboard/) for more info.